# Finding the value of a for which the plane and a line are parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I need to find the value of a for which the line r which is passing through the point Q=(0, 0, 0) and P=(a, 1, 2) is parallel to the plane with equation

$$ \alpha: a(x+y)-z=0 $$

So, I know from where I could start but I get stuck.

First, I find the parametric equation of r, knowing that it's passing through Q and P I get a directional vector:

$$ OP = (a, 1, 2) $$

Using Q as a starting system, I find its equation

$$ r: \begin{cases} x=at \\y=t \\z=2t \end{cases}$$

To see if the plane and the line are parallel, I'd do the cross poduct between two directional vectors and see if it's 0. However, I don't know how I should do it considering I have a real parameter in both the equation of the line and the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way here is to determine $a$ such that the line directional vector and the plane normal vector are perpendicular. For this, their dot product needs to be zero, i.e.

$$(a,1,2) \cdot (a,a,-1) = 0$$

(The coordinates of the plane normal vector are the coefficients next to $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively in the implicit equation of the plane.)

Comment: Alright, so the dot product is 0 when a=1 or -2. Still confused on what to do next, though.

Comment: @user3819175 You found the value(s) for $a$. Wasn't that the whole task? And you made a mistake because you should get $a=1$ or $a=-2$. (the solutions of $a^2+a-2=0$) The dot product being zero implies that the line directional vector and the plane normal vector are perpendicular, meaning that the line and the plane are parallel.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wrote a=0 instead of 1 for some reasons. Thank you very much for your explanation and help.